# Prism Xamarin Forms - using shared service in shared service

Tags: xamarin.forms, prism

Hy i wrote a couple of shared services in my prism application.
I´m now at the point where i want to chain my servces. I want to use the services in another service. For example i want to use mit Loggerservice to log errors not only in my ViewModel, but also in the other Services.

Is that possible in a better way than i do now?

Now i´m requesting both services in my ViewModels constructor.
Than i call a method of service one and give them a reference to the service two as a parameter.

I think there is a better way of doing this in Prism?!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general yes you can register and reuse services within other services. For example you could have:

```
public interface ILogger
{
    void Log(string message);
}

public interface IApiService
{
    Task DoStuff();
}

public class ApiService : IApiService
{
    ILogger _logger { get; }

    public ApiService(ILogger logger)
    {
        _logger = logger
    }

    public Task DoStuff()
    {
        // Do DoStuff
        _logger.Log("Some Message");
    }
}
```

You however should not attempt to use INavigationService within your services as the NavigationService requires an understanding of which Page you are navigating from to work correctly.